Show that the dual Lefschetz operator applied to a two-form $\alpha$ is explicitly given by $\Lambda \alpha =\sum_i \alpha(x_i, y_i)$.

Choose an orthonormal basis $x_1, y_1 = J(x_1), \dots , x_n, y_n = J(x_n)$ of an euclidian vector space $V$ endowed with a compatible almost complex structure $J$. Show that the dual Lefschetz operator applied to a two-form $\alpha$ is explicitly given by $\Lambda \alpha =\sum_i \alpha(x_i, y_i)$.

So given a $\alpha \in \bigwedge^2 V^*$, $\Lambda \alpha \in \bigwedge^0 V^* = \Bbb C$. We know that $\Lambda$ is the adjoint of the map $L(\tau)=\omega \wedge \tau$ where $\omega$ is the fundamental form. So $$\langle \Lambda\alpha,1\rangle = \langle \alpha, L(1)\rangle = \langle \alpha,\omega\rangle.$$
Can I do something to $\langle \alpha,\omega\rangle$ with the Hodge $*$-operator to get to the desired conclusion?

The compatibility relation allows us to write $\omega$ in terms of the given basis $x_i, y_i$: we have $\omega = \sum_i x_i^\flat \wedge y_i^\flat$, where $\flat$ is the musical isomorphism $(x_i^\flat(v) = \langle x_i, v \rangle)$.
Then $\langle \alpha, \omega \rangle = \sum_i \langle \alpha, x_i^\flat \wedge y_i^\flat \rangle = \sum_i \alpha(x_i \wedge y_i)$ as desired. The final equality can be checked by $\langle \alpha, x_i^\flat \wedge y_i^\flat \rangle = \langle \alpha, (x_i \wedge y_i)^\flat \rangle = \langle \iota_{x_i \wedge y_i} \alpha, 1 \rangle = \alpha(x_i \wedge y_i)$, where $\iota$ denotes contraction (i.e. the adjoint to the wedge product).

$\alpha$ is a $2$-form so what exactly does $\alpha(x_i \wedge y_i)$ mean?

$\alpha(x_i \wedge y_i) = \alpha(x_i, y_i)$. Note that $\Lambda^2 (V^) = (\Lambda^2 V)^$ canonically.
